# Understanding proof that if $\rho_{xy} >0$ but $\rho_{yx}<1$, then x is transient.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

> Theorem:
>
> If $\rho_{xy} >0$ but $\rho_{yx}<1$, then, x is transient.

Proof:

In general, let the Markov chain from state x to y be done so in K steps.

Then, $P^{K}_{xy}=P\left ( x,y_{1} \right )\cdot \cdot \cdot P(y_{K-1},y)>0$

From here, it is necessary that I show that the probability for the Markov chain at state x NOT to transit to state x at time of first return has a probability greater than $P^{K}_{xy}=P\left ( x,y_{1} \right )\cdot \cdot \cdot P(y_{K-1},y)>0$

I am unable to show this.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Can you define your notation more clearly; what is $\rho_{xy}$ in this context? Also your equation $P^K_{xy} = P(x,y_1)\cdots P(y_{K-1},y)$ is not correct (or says something different to what you think?); if $P^K_{xy}$ is meant to denote the probability of going from $x$ to $y$ in $K$ steps then the formula should read $$P^{K}_{xy} = \sum_{v_1,\ldots, v_{K-1} \in V} \prod_{k=1}^K P(v_{k-1}, v_k),$$ where $v_{0} = x, \, v_{K} = y$. That is we sum over all possible paths, not just a single path.

Comment: Hopefully you found my answer below helpful. If so, would you please consider upvoting and accepting it? Stack exchange sites survive by people donating their time to help each other, and upvoting is an easy way to give back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the detail you give above I am not certain that I understand your question correctly, but I think the below interpretation seems plausible.

I am assuming that the notation you use that $\rho_{xy}$ is the probability that the hitting time at $y$ of the Markov chain started from $x$, is finite.

That is, if we define the first return time to a state $y$ of the Markov chain $X_n$ to be 
 $$\tau_y^+ = \inf\{ n \geq 1 \, \colon \, X_n = y\},$$
then I will assume that $\rho_{xy}$ denotes the probability that the return time to $y$ is finite, starting from $x$
$$\rho_{xy} = \mathbf P_x[ \tau_y^+ < \infty].$$
For $x$ to be a transient state, we need to show that $\rho_{xx} < 1$.

---

To do this, we use the law of total probability and condition on whether or not the Markov chain hits $y$; we have
\begin{align*}
\rho_{xx} & = \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty] \\
& = \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \, \tau_y^+ < \infty ] \,\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_y^+ < \infty] \, \,  
+ \, \,\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \,\tau_y^+ = \infty  ]
\,\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_y^+ = \infty]\\
& = \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \, \tau_y^+ < \infty ] \,\rho_{xy} \, \,  
+ \, \,\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \,\tau_y^+ = \infty  ]
\,(1 - \rho_{xy})\\
& \leq
\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \, \tau_y^+ < \infty ] \,\rho_{xy} \, \,  
+ \,
\,(1 - \rho_{xy}) 
\end{align*}
where in the last line we simply used the fact that $0 \leq \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \,\tau_y^+ = \infty  ] \leq 1$. Rearranging the above, we have
$$ \rho_{xx} \leq 1 - \rho_{xy}\bigg( 1  - \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \, \tau_y^+ < \infty ] \bigg)$$
However, conditioned on the fact that the Markov chain visits $y$: the probability of returning to $x$ starting at $x$ is the same as the probability of returning to $x$ starting from $y$. That is
$$ \mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty \, | \, \tau_y^+ < \infty ] = \mathbf{P}_y[ \tau_x^+ < \infty  ] = \rho_{yx},$$
so we have
$$ \rho_{xx} \leq 1 - \rho_{xy}( 1- \rho_{yx}).$$
When you combine this with the knowledge that $\rho_{xy} > 0$ and $\rho_{yx}<1$, it follows that $\rho_{xx} < 1$, and hence is transient.